# No pages to convert , k2pdf

Tags: linux, pdf

k2pdf does not detect that i want to extract pages 5-10

```
sudo /bin/k2pdfopt  Mer.pdf -p 5-10 -s -ui-  -o  Con.pdf
```

I am getting the error :

```
No pages to convert (-p 5-10)!
```

Manual: `https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/man1/k2pdfopt.1.html`
Examples: `https://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/help/custom3.shtml`
`https://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/help/filesize.shtml`

Comment: Another simple command `sudo /bin/k2pdfopt  -ui- -bpc 2  Mer.pdf -o Con.pdf` gives similar error  , first it reads 3 pages `Reading 3 pages from`,  but than it outputs 6 pages with message `SOURCE PAGE 3 of 3 (8.3 x 11.7 in) ... 0 pages saved  6 pages written to`. maybe my computer is hacked ??

Answer (score 0):

Simplified command to

```
sudo /bin/k2pdfopt  -ui-   -wrap- -col 1   -fc- -w 1s -h 1s -ocr- -bpc 2 -p 1-6  Mer.pdf  -o  Con.pdf
```

it ave 2 pages instead of 6, and anlysed only 3 pages :

```
SOURCE PAGE 3 (3 of 3) (8.3 x 11.7 in) ... 0 pages saved
2 pages written
```

Trying many simple commands involving option -p, or without, decided that solution is to reinstal `k2pdf`.
In Linux, it means remove the old installation with packagist,
downlaoded new from [https://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/download/?-1680282346][1]
pasted to bin

```
sudo chmod 777 /bin/k2pdfopt
```

WORKS!
[1]: https://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/download/?-1680282346